# Как сделать обратный перенос в CSS flex?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Я хочу сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
<div>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
</div>
```

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
aside {
    height: 300px;
    flex: 1 1 24vw;
    min-width: 225px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
aside:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #838383;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
</div>
<div>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
</div>

<style>
    div:nth-child(even){
       flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
</style>
```